# Android CharSequence Number Detection(0-9) in one statement without using if else

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I am new in android and trying to make a calculator...

Now i have extracted whole expression in a charSequence variable.

e.g 30+69-(3-10)

Now i need to detect whether the first character of charSequence variable is either a number (0-9) or a character/operator.

i can use get.subSequence(0,1) but dont want to compare it with every number to decide whether its a number or not and if its a number then which one it is....

How can i compare it with every number using fewer conditions and also extract that specific number....

Comment: Is that a real problem or trying to do premature optimization?

Comment: hehe. i have strtd learning android. i have done programming on c++ b4. no optimization.. just trying to understand basics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Character.isDigit(someChar)
```

This will tell you if a char is a number or not.

If it is not, you can assume it is an operator and treat it as such.

So an implementation could look like:

```
CharSequence chars = "1+2-3";

for(int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++ ) {
    if (Character.isDigit(chars.charAt(i))) {
        //is digit
    } else {
        //is operator
    }
}
```

*I don't have a java compiler available, so I cant promise that works at the moment.

Comment: i m using variable of type 'charSequence'  not character type to store the expression.... this function is not available in charSequence class...

Comment: isDigit is a static function on the Character class.  You can pass it any character - such as the one returned from CharSequence.charAt(0), say.

Comment: what if the digit is a two digit number?? is it efficient to run it in a loop?

Comment: even if it is two digits, you still know its a number. so if you focus on eliminating the operators or non-numbers, you will only be left with numbers you can easily evaluate later. It depends how you write it.